# MapView shows empty tiles in GoogleMaps API v2 for Android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm moving my app to the new Google's API for Android. I've decided to use the MapView and not the Fragment since the map is a part of a Fragment.
I've succeeded to show a map with the MapFragment, but when trying to do the same with the MapView it just shows empty tiles.
Does anyone has a clew what I'm missing?
These are the permissions from the Manifest file:

```
<permission android:name="com.beezer.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" 
                 android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.beezer.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I don't get any error in the log.

Comment: What is the difference between MapFragment and MapView

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you forwarded all the Activity life cycle methods as written here 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#mapview

"Users of this class must forward all the Activity life cycle methods - such as onCreate(), onDestroy(), onResume(), and onPause() - to the corresponding methods in the MapView class."

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try {
       MapsInitializer.initialize(mContext);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mapView.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
   super.onResume();
   mapView.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mapView.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: That could be the problem.
Eventually I solved it using nested Fragments which is supported in the new support library. That made the solution much more elegant.

Comment: I have the same problem, where is the mapView variable set? I use custom layout for a fragment, this layout contains `MapView` and the instance of this `MapView` can be obtained only during the `onViewCreated` call, where the layout is inflated. But the `onCreate` method is called earlier so the mapView variable is null in this time...

Answer (score 3):

There are only two issues I can this of :

1. The signatures of your build do not match with your maps api key
2. You are not using MapView from inside a MapActivity. It will not work otherwise.

Comment: My api key works because if I use a MapFragment in the xml view the map shows up just fine.